# Offline Progressive web app not open error message is Can't connect to site(Like native error popup message)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeGEu.jpg)Actually when I open my pwa application on my mobile application with a network connection, it works fine, but if the app is opened without a network connection, then it shows an error, like native popup box with blue ok button.

This is my build folder service worker
`

```
importScripts("/precache-manifest.785730fc4a51dce11dbb95ef5aa21604.js");

self.addEventListener("message", event => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

workbox.core.clientsClaim();
[enter image description here][1]
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});

workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(
  workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL("/index.html"),
  {
    blacklist: [/^\/_/, /\/[^\/]+\.[^\/]+$/]
  }
);
```

`

This is my public folder service worker

```
self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
  const cacheWhitelist = [CACHE_NAME];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(keyList =>
      Promise.all(
        keyList.map(key => {
          if (!cacheWhitelist.includes(key)) {
            console.log("Deleting cache: " + key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        })
      )
    )
  );
});

self.addEventListener("install", function(event) {

    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
        fetch("manifest.json")
          .then(response => {
            response.json();
          })
          .then(assets => {
            console.log(assets);
            const urlsToCache = ["/", assets["main.js"]];
            cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            console.log("cached");
          });
      })
    );

});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {

    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );

});

function isFunction(obj) {
  return obj && {}.toString.call(obj) === "[object Function]";
}

function runFunctionString(funcStr) {
  if (funcStr.trim().length > 0) {
    var func = new Function(funcStr);
    if (isFunction(func)) {
      func();
    }
  }
}
```

[I facing this error when i open my pwa after some 2 or 3 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4NX8.jpg)

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand. Could you add some screenshots maybe? Also, I'm sure this is not actually in your code `[enter image description here][1]`, right?

Comment: Hi, @pate you found an image is this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeGEu.jpg Please update when you found any solution. I am facing this error when I open PWA after 5 or 6 hours.